# Powerpoint and multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

Using my laptop and the meeting room projector, I can have Powerpoint on the "2nd monitor" (the projector). But when I run the slideshow it always shows on the first monitor (the laptop).

Is there a way to force Powerpoint to show the slideshow on the same monitor as the app itself is being displayed? I'd really like to be able to multitask during meetings, rather than having 2 screens both be dominated by Powerpoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Slide Show tab of powerpoint on the far right, there is an option that says **Show presentation on:** and it will let you select which monitor to put the presentation. Simply select from the dropdown whichever monitor has the app itself running.

[image]

Comment: perfect! (padding)